# How to enable faceted search in Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, django-oscar

I am very new to Oscar, I have been trying to use the builtin support for faceted search for my Oscar project but I have no clue (can't find any documentation).

I have :

- My elastic search running at port 9200
- Haystack settings :

  ```
  HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
          'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
          'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
      },
  }
  ```
- I was able to index my catalogue successfully with `python manage.py rebuild_index`

I tried :

- But my /search/ page still lists only categories to click through.
- I digged in deeper into the `views.py` in search app (from oscar) and found its `MultiFacetedSearchView` is rendering `search/results.html`
- 'search/results.html' seems to be looping over categories and rendering categories only. - - Nothing related to faceted search.

I don't know if i am missing something or what ?
How should I enable faceted search for my catelogue ? [ If its a 1 step process ]
Even if its not a 1 step process, then can you link me to some code snippets or documentation ( I was enable to find any ) ?

[ Also, I am new to haystack as well so may be I am asking something stupid ]

Comment: My whole catelogue is indexed in elastic search, but the `/search/` doesn't seems to be using it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from the official developers :

[Official bug response for faceted search](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/issues/749)

- Oscar 0.5 doesn't have a support for faceted search as of now.
- Oscar 0.6 will be supporting faceted search.

Atleast got an answer as `No` otherwise I would have killed more time to find it.